# python pandas колонки

Tags: python, pandas

Есть такая таблица

| показатель | fact2020 | fact2021 | fact2022 | plan2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 143 | 24 | 124 | 324 |
| b | 234 | 1 | 324 | 6583 |

Хочу привести ее к следующему виду

| показатель | признак | год | значение |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | fact | 2020 | 143 |
| a | fact | 2021 | 24 |
| a | fact | 2022 | 124 |
| a | plan | 2023 | 324 |
| b | fact | 2020 | 234 |
| b | fact | 2021 | 1 |
| b | fact | 2022 | 324 |
| b | plan | 2023 | 6583 |

Comment: Куда-то в сторону `pivot` или `pivot_table` нужно копать

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
res = df.pivot(columns = "показатель", values = ["fact2020", "fact2021", "fact2022", "plan2023"]).T.reset_index()
res['признак'] = res['level_0'].str[:-4]
res['год'] = res['level_0'].str[-4:]
res["значение"] = res[0].fillna(res[1])
res = res.drop(columns=["level_0", 0, 1]).sort_values("показатель")
```

res:

```
  показатель признак   год  значение
0          a    fact  2020     143.0
2          a    fact  2021      24.0
4          a    fact  2022     124.0
6          a    plan  2023     324.0
1          b    fact  2020     234.0
3          b    fact  2021       1.0
5          b    fact  2022     324.0
7          b    plan  2023    6583.0
```